# Continuity of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given that a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ and that $f(r)=0$ $\forall r \in \Bbb Q$, I need to show that $f(x) = 0$, $\forall x \in \Bbb R$.

Can anyone advise on how to begin this, what type of method to use? I'm trying to train myself to rely more on utilizing theorems that work well together rather than resorting to brute force (my usual method).

I began a proof by contradiction but was not successful. Thank you.

Comment: What sort of theorems do you know? For instance, what theorems might make use of the fact that the rationals are dense?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For any irrational number there is a sequence of rationals converging to it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to show $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Hint: if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, then by continuity of $f$ you have 
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$.